# discord.py How to add a new json key to all users one time

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot saves the users info in a json file like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh12z.jpg

So I need to add a new json key `(name="House", value=False)` to all users.
I tried before `json.dump(house, json_file)` bot not works.

**Important info:** I have these functions:

To open a new json account:

```py
async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    if str(user.id) in users:
        house = users[str(user.id)]['House'] = False
        with open("main.json", 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(house))
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["House"] = False
```

To read json file:

```py
async def get_bank_data():
    with open("main.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users
```

**Another info:** `user` value is `ctx.author`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a 1 time method where you loop over all users in your json to add the new field, something like this:

```py
async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    for user in users:
        house = user['House'] = False
        
    with open("main.json", 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(house))
```

If you want to add the field for every user in your Server, you could loop over all members to add to your json like so:

```py
users = await get_bank_data()

async for member in guild.fetch_members():
    house = users[str(member.id)]['House'] = False

        
with open("main.json", 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(house))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run this script locally to add the "House" key to every user within the `main.json` file

```py
with open("main.json", "r") as f:
    bank_data = json.load(f)

# scroll through every user
for key in bank_data.keys():
   # If there is no "House" key for a user
   if bank_data[key].get("House") is None:
       # Add the key
       bank_data[key]["House"] = False

# Save the json
with open("main.json", 'w') as f:
   f.write(json.dumps(bank_data))
```

Btw `get_bank_data` dont need to be a `async` funciton as it doesn't use any ascynchronous functionnalities

Comment: `get_bank_data` It's `async` because I use it in every command

Comment: @AliFGT that doesn’t really explain anything